# JavaScript: Show / Hide <DIV> based on URL string

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, show-hide

I need to show a DIV on two pages (URL's) but not on the others.
(I have jQuery on the pages if that helps.). I'm a complete noob so all help is very much appreciate. Thank's!

**Case (1) where I want to show the DIV:**

- On the start page, when the web browser address field reads 'www.mydomin.com'
- The start page is PHP so I guess the full URL is 'www.mydomin.com/index.php'

**Case (2):**

- 'www.mydomin.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&title.html&Itemid=1&lang=en'
- **WHERE this part is alway the same**
- 'www.mydomin.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&'
- **AND this part is always unique**
- 'title.html&Itemid=1&lang=en

Example

```
    if (url == 'www.mydomin.com' or 'www.mydomin.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&') {

 do this

    xxxxxxxx

 else

        nothing
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work, if I understand the question correctly

```
var url = document.location.href;

if (url.indexOf('www.mydomin.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&') >= 0) {
  $('#div_id').hide();
} else {
  $('#div_id').show();
}
```

But really, if you use PHP anyway, you should figure out how to not render the div in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code! I tried it but could not get it to work (it renders the div on all pages). I think you understood the question right except one thing - I also have to check it the URL is the start page 'www.mydomain.com/index.php' with no extra characters after the URL. Regarding the PHP suggestion I think you are absolutely right - my problem is that I have no control over the PHP because its generated from a database. So this is sort of a hack to get things on the page that I cant otherwise.

Comment: are you sure you replaced my #div_id with the correct selector?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the [query string](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20020107.asp) and show/hide the div based on the result.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I'm afraid I'm to much of a noob to understand all the information on the page you linked to. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I also think it should be handled from PHP code instead from JavaScript. And div should not be rendered in first place.

Comment: Thank's. I agree I would if it was possible (pls see first comment).

Answer (score 0):

You can target a specific query parameter of the URL using [`window.location.search`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp). Using the below code, you can find an exact match anddisplay/hide the HTML element:

```js
var firstURLParam = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&')[0];
var datGuiEle = document.getElementById("elemID");
if(firstURLParam == "debug"){
    datGuiEle.style.display = "block";
}
else {
  datGuiEle.style.display = "none";
}
```